# PeerDependencies with npm > v7

Tags: npm

As explained in the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies), after npm v7 migration, now PeerDependencies are installed by default. Here is the behavior from the documentation:

> Trying to install another plugin with a conflicting requirement may cause an error if the tree cannot be resolved correctly.

When is a plugin considered as a conflicting requirement?
What do they mean by the tree cannot be resolved correctly?

Therefore, I created different use cases to have a better understanding, tell me if I am correct.

### Use case 1

###### Package.json of my project

```
{
  //...
  "dependencies": {
    "a": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

###### Package.json of a

```
{
  //...
  "peerDependencies": {
    "b": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Here is the result:

```
node_modules
  |--- a (v 1.0.0)
  |--- b (v 2.0.0)
```

### Use case 2

###### Package.json of my project

```
{
  //...
  "dependencies": {
    "a": "1.0.0",
    "b": "2.5.0"
  }
}
```

###### Package.json of a

```
{
  //...
  "peerDependencies": {
    "b": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Here is the result:

```
node_modules
  |--- a (v 1.0.0)
  |--- b (v 2.5.0)
```

### Use case 3

###### Package.json of my project

```
{
  //...
  "dependencies": {
    "a": "1.0.0",
    "b": "3.2.0"
  }
}
```

###### Package.json of a

```
{
  //...
  "peerDependencies": {
    "b": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Here is the result:

```
node_modules
  |--- a (v 1.0.0)
       |--- node_modules
              |--- b (v 2.0.0)
  |--- b (v 3.2.0)
```

Does the last use case work? In which use case, it can not resolve the tree?

Answer (score 0):

If npm cannot resolve a depdendency tree, you would not have gotten everything installed at all (nothing in `node_modules`, no `package-lock.json`). It would throw an error by default since, before any installation, the npm resolves the whole dependency tree. You might want to force and hide conflicts with `--legacy-peer-deps` to disrespect `peerDependencies` and other version mismatches, however, I don't recommend doing it.

Case 1: no conflict. The main package does not have a direct `b` in the `package.json`. The `b@2.0.0` package was hoisted to the top level (npm uses the flat node_modules approach) and installed since it is required to exist for your child dependency.

Case 2: no conflict. Your main package has `b@2.5.0` direct depedency which completely satisfies A's child requirements to have `b@2.*.*` as peerDeps. Therefore, `b@2.5.0` was installed without any issues as is.

Case 3: peer conflict. npm will throw the error `ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree` since it cannot resolve by itself. Nothing will be done neither node_modules nor a lock file.

**Issue**: The child package `a` requires the package `b` to have a version of `2.*.*`, but your main package has a higher version `b@3.2.0`. The difference is in a major version. So, you are trying to integrate non-compatible modules (packages).

**Solution**: You should either upgrade `a` to a newer version that has `peerDependencies` containing `"b": "^3.0.0"` instead of `"b": "^2.0.0"` OR downgrade `b` of the main package from `3.2.0` to be any `2.*.*`.

**Side story**: If there is a case you definitely want to force 'b' of 'a' to use its own different version of `b`, move `b` from peerDependencies to dependencies inside `a`'s package.json. This way, npm will keep its own version of `b` in a nested manner inside node_modules. npm will not hoist it since there is already another version higher in the tree. Thus, `b@3.2.0` will be stored on the top level, and `b@2.0.0` will be installed as well as you showed in your last code snippet.